# Multiple polygon to shapefile in XYZ format

Tags: shapefile, polygon, pyshp

I have an array of gridded data in XYZ format. I am trying to write shapefile (*.shp) file with multiple polygons with the [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) Python libraries.

I am able to make it for only one polygon with the following code:

```
import shapefile


w = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.POLYGONZ)
w.poly([[ [398010.0 7541990.0 280.4], [398010.0 7541980.0 281.5], [398020.0 7541980.0 280.9], [398020.0 7541990.0 279.8], [398010.0 7541990.0 280.4] ]], shapeType=15 )
w.field('NAME')
w.record('PolyZTest')
w.save('MyPolyZ')
```

However, I am not able for several polygons.

How can be done? For example, for the following four polygons?

```
POLYGONZ((398000.0 7542000.0 279.9, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398000.0 7542000.0 279.9))
POLYGONZ((398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398020.0 7541990.0 279.8, 398020.0 7542000.0 278.8, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4))
POLYGONZ((398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398000.0 7541980.0 282.1, 398010.0 7541980.0 281.5, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0))
POLYGONZ((398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7541980.0 281.5, 398020.0 7541980.0 280.9, 398020.0 7541990.0 279.8, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4))
```

If there are other easier command line options writing all polygons to a file, also could be a good choice.

Maybe the only possibility is to create shapefiles and then merge them?

Comment: have you looked up mpolygon

Comment: Brad, that is only for AutoCAD as I can see, deosn't it? I cannot find anything about mpolygon related with pyshp or similar. Can you explain what do you refer to?

Comment: http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Comment: Do you refer to PolygonM? That rings do not allow XYZ space, only XYZ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format, the correct syntax is:

> "POLYGON Z ((398000.0 7542000.0 279.9, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398000.0 7542000.0 279.9))"

and not `POLYGONZ(` but it is very easy to transform your original format to correct WKT

```py
poly = 'POLYGONZ((398000.0 7542000.0 279.9, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398000.0 7542000.0 279.9))'
poly.replace('POLYGONZ','POLYGON Z ')
print poly
'POLYGON Z ((398000.0 7542000.0 279.9, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398000.0 7542000.0 279.9))'
```

Then you can use any Python module which allows to convert the WKT format to valid coordinates for PyShp ([Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html), [PyGeoif](https://github.com/cleder/pygeoif), ...)

With PyGeoif (easier to use):

```py
from pygeoif import geometry
poly = 'POLYGON Z ((398000.0 7542000.0 279.9, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398000.0 7542000.0 279.9))' 
geom = geometry.from_wkt(poly)
print poly.exterior.coords
((398000.0, 7542000.0, 279.89999999999998), (398000.0, 7541990.0, 281.0), (398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.39999999999998), (398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.39999999999998), (398000.0, 7542000.0, 279.89999999999998))
```

So, first build a list with all the geometries

```py
geometries = ['POLYGON Z ((398000.0 7542000.0 279.9, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398000.0 7542000.0 279.9))','POLYGONZ((398010.0 7542000.0 279.4, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398020.0 7541990.0 279.8, 398020.0 7542000.0 278.8, 398010.0 7542000.0 279.4))','POLYGONZ((398000.0 7541990.0 281.0, 398000.0 7541980.0 282.1, 398010.0 7541980.0 281.5, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398000.0 7541990.0 281.0))','POLYGONZ((398010.0 7541990.0 280.4, 398010.0 7541980.0 281.5, 398020.0 7541980.0 280.9, 398020.0 7541990.0 279.8, 398010.0 7541990.0 280.4))']
```

Then create the shapefile with a simple for loop:

```py
import shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGONZ)
w.field('test','N')
for i,poly in enumerate(geometries):
      w.poly([geometry.from_wkt(poly).exterior.coords])
      w.record(i)

w.save('testpysh')
```

Result:

[image]

But is is  as easy with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) and the  [**geo_interface**](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) protocol ( GeoJSON-like)

```py
import fiona
from pygeoif import geometry
# schema of the shapefile
schema = {'geometry': '3D Polygon','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
# creation of the shapefile
with fiona.open('testpysh2.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
    for i,poly in enumerate(geometries):
       output.write({'geometry':geometry.from_wkt(poly).__geo_interface__, 'properties':{'test':i}})
```

Control

```py
for shape in fiona.open('testpysh2.shp):
    print shape
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(398000.0, 7542000.0, 279.89999999999998), (398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.39999999999998), (398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.39999999999998), (398000.0, 7541990.0, 281.0), (398000.0, 7542000.0, 279.89999999999998)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'test', 0)])}
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.39999999999998), (398020.0, 7542000.0, 278.80000000000001), (398020.0, 7541990.0, 279.80000000000001), (398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.39999999999998), (398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.39999999999998)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'test', 1)])}
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(398000.0, 7541990.0, 281.0), (398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.39999999999998), (398010.0, 7541980.0, 281.5), (398000.0, 7541980.0, 282.10000000000002), (398000.0, 7541990.0, 281.0)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '2', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'test', 2)])}
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.39999999999998), (398020.0, 7541990.0, 279.80000000000001), (398020.0, 7541980.0, 280.89999999999998), (398010.0, 7541980.0, 281.5), (398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.39999999999998)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '3', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'test', 3)])}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing good so far. Just try to change the syntax of your polygonz declaration. I did it for you. Here is the complete working code with comments where neccessary:

```py
# import shapefile library  
import shapefile

#create an in memory polygon shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.POLYGONZ)
#add a name field to it
w.field('NAME')

#fill name field with polygon1 value
w.record('Polygon1')
#fill geometry of the feature with this polygon coordinates
w.poly([[[398000.0, 7542000.0, 279.9], [398000.0 ,7541990.0, 281.0], [398010.0 ,7541990.0, 280.4], [398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.4], [398000.0, 7542000.0, 279.9]]],shapeType=15)

w.record('Polygon2')
w.poly([[[398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.4], [398010.0 ,7541990.0, 280.4], [398020.0 ,7541990.0, 279.8], [398020.0, 7542000.0, 278.8], [398010.0, 7542000.0, 279.4]]],shapeType=15)

w.record('Polygon3')
w.poly([[[398000.0, 7541990.0, 281.0], [398000.0 ,7541980.0, 282.1], [398010.0 ,7541980.0, 281.5], [398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.4], [398000.0, 7541990.0, 281.0]]],shapeType=15)

w.record('Polygon4')
w.poly([[[398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.4], [398010.0 ,7541980.0, 281.5], [398020.0 ,7541980.0, 280.9], [398020.0, 7541990.0, 279.8], [398010.0, 7541990.0, 280.4]]],shapeType=15)

#save the save file to a file
w.save(r'D:\Cache\MyPolyZ')
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This answer is totally correct, but I found that the answer of @gene is more general in case of having WKT files or a file with several coordinates.
Thank you for the answer!